# MySQL - FULLTEXT in BOOLEAN mode + Relevance using views field

Tags: mysql, database-design, full-text-search

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `search`
(
    `id` BIGINT(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `string` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `views` BIGINT(16) NOT NULL,
    FULLTEXT(string)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

It has a total of 5,395,939 entries. To perform a search on a term (like 'a'), I use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE MATCH(string) AGAINST('+a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY `views` DESC LIMIT 10
```

But it's really slow =(. The query above took 15.4423 seconds to perform. Obviously, it's fast without sorting by `views`, which takes less than 0.002s.

I'm using ft_min_word_len=1 and ft_stopword_file=

Is there any way to use the views as the relevance in the fulltext search, without making it too slow? I want the search term "a b" match "big apple", for example, but not "ibg apple" (just need the search prefixes to match).

Thanks

Comment: To understand your problem, it would be helpful to have EXPLAIN output for your query. Number of returned rows, and cardinality of the indexes would probably be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not necessary anymore =D. The problem is that it matches about 460 thousands of rows for '+a*'. When I limit it to 10 results, it's not a problem anymore, since it only needs to return me the 10 first results. But if I ask MySQL to sort by views, it will still need to get all those 460 thousands results, sort, and then return me only 10. It can't know what are the 10 bests without sorting them all =/. I guess there is no solution for this using MySQL. I've searched and studied a lot to try to do this, and found no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered my question, I'm posting my solution (not the one I would expect to see if I was googling, since it isn't so easy to apply as a simple database-design would be, but it's still a solution to this problem).
I couldn't really solve it with any engine or function used by MySQL. Sorry =/.

So, I decided to develop my own software to do it (in C++, but you can apply it in any other language).
If what you are looking for is a method to search for some prefixes of words in small strings (the average length of my strings is 15), so you can use the following algorithm:

```
1. Create a trie. Each word of each string is put on the trie.
   Each leaf has a list of the ids that match that word.
2. Use a map/dictionary (or an array) to memorize the informations
   for each id (map[id] = information).
```

Searching for a string:
Note: The string will be in the format "word1 word2 word3...". If it has some symbols, like #, @, $, you might consider them as " " (spaces).
Example: "Rafael Perrella"

```
1. Search for the prefix "Rafael" in the trie. Put all the ids you
   get in a set (a Binary-Search Tree that ignores repeated values).
   Let's call this set "mainSet".
2. Search for the prefix "Perrella" in the trie. For each result,
   put them in a second set (secSet) if and only if they are already
   in the mainSet. Then, clear mainSet and do mainSet = secSet.
3. IF there are still words lefting to search, repeat the second step
   for all those words.
```

After these steps, you will have a set with all the results. Make a vector using a pair for the (views, id) and sort the vector in descending order. So, just get the results you want... I've limited to 30 results.

Note: you can sort the words first to remove those with the same prefix (for example, in "Jan Ja Jan Ra" you only need "Jan Ra"). I will not explain about it since the algorithm is pretty obvious.

This algorithm may be bad sometimes (for example, if I search for "a b c d e f ... z", I will search the entire trie...). So, I made an improvement.

```
1. For each "id" in your map, create also a small trie, that will
   contain the words of the string (include a trie for each m[id]...
   m[id].trie?).
```

Then, to make a search:

```
1. Choose the longest word in the search string (it's not guaranteed,
   but it is probably the word with the fewest results in the trie...).
2. Apply the step 1 of the old algorithm.
3. Make a vector with the ids in the mainSet.
4. Let's make the final vector. For each id in the vector you've created
   in step 3, search in the trie of this id (m[id].trie?) for all words
   in the search string. If it includes all words, it's a valid id and
   you might include it in the final vector; else, just ignore this id.
5. Repeat step 4 until there are no more ids to verify. After that, just
   sort the final vector for <views, id>.
```

Now, I use the database just as a way to easily store and load my data. All the queries in this table are directly asked to this software. When I add or remove a record, I send both to the DB and to the software, so I always keep both updated. It costs me about 30s to load all the data, but then the queries are fast (0.03s for the slowest ones, 0.001s in average; using my own notebook, didn't try it in a dedicated hosting, where it might be much faster).